# Transverse through directories in python

Tags: python

I am trying to transverse through directories and count as I am going along so at the the end program output will be like:

```
output:
 ./file last accessed 1/1/2000 # just sample date


./dirA has 1 file and 1 sub-dir
./dirA/test/ has 5 files
```

Here is the code but Im out of ideas now:

```
directories = [startDir]
#!/usr/bin/python
import os,os.path, time


startDir = os.getcwd()
fileCount=0
directoryCount=0

while len(directories)>0:
directory = directories.pop()
for name in os.listdir(directory):
     fullpath = os.path.join(directory,name)
     lastAccess = os.stat(fullpath).st_atime
     accessTime = time.asctime(time.gmtime(lastAccess))
     if os.path.isfile(fullpath):
         print fullpath +" is file"+" "+ accessTime  
         fileCount+=1
     elif os.path.isdir(fullpath):
         directories.append(fullpath)
         directoryCount+=1
         print fullpath + " "+ accessTime

print fileCount, directoryCount # only test printing for now
```

So that is where I am at right now. Just in case I wasnt clear, I want to list files in the current directory (and sub directories) along with the time they were last accessed. I also want to list the directories with how many files and sub dir in them.

Comment: Why reinvent the recursion wheel here? `os.walk()` does this much better.

Comment: I have tried the os.walk but still am at a dead when it comes to outpuuting the number files in the directory (excluding files in sub directories within the directory)

Comment: The third value yielded by `os.walk()` is a list of all files (excluding subdirectories), so a `len(filenames)` is all you need there.

Answer (score 1):

A hint using `os.walk`:

```
for x,y,z in os.walk('your_path'):
...     for file in z:
...         print fullpath + ": "+ str(time.asctime(time.gmtime(os.stat(fullpath).st_atime)))
```

`os.walk` give three tuples dir,subdir,files